# I am getting the following error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android-layout

I have some C++ experience but am now starting with java in eclipse for android.
I am going through the tutorials of eclipse and am having a problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<TextView <== HERE I GET THE error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Type here:">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/entry"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
    android:layout_below="@id/label">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/entry"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:text="OK">
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ok"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/ok"
    android:text="Cancel">
```

I have no idea what the problem with my code is, please help

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

End tag is missing for all elements .